# How do I define a list of properties

Tags: vb.net

I have a class called "heater".  One of the properties is "designstatus", a string.  I want to limit the property to one of three choices; "current", "obsolete", "notdesigned".  How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). E.g.:

```
Public Enum DesignStatus
    Current
    Obsolete
    NotDesigned
End Enum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an Enum, but as an Enum is an Integer this isn't going to completely do what you want, so I would suggest doing something similar to this:

```
Public Enum DesignStatuses
   Current
   Obsolete
   NotDesigned
End Enum
```

So when you need to get the actual String name of the Enum that you have used you can do:

`DesignStatus.ToString("G")`

Which will return the actual name of the constant instead of the value.